# Unable to upload app bundle using Play API

Tags: android, python-3.x, google-api, google-play

I have a script running which automatically uploads a bundle and creates an internal testing release in the Play Store. This script works perfectly for a non-draft app. However, I wanted to set that up already for a new app I'm working on, which I cannot currently put in a non-draft status (I don't have any version ready for production), but I still want to be able to give it to some internal testers and update their versions as I'm working on the app. The full script is below with some data anonymized:

```py
import os
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# Get the app ID from the environment.
app_id = "com.company.app.app"
print(f"App ID set to {app_id}.")

# Get the APK file path from the environment.
aab_file_path = "/output/com.company.app.app-Signed.aab"
print(f"Path to bundle set to {aab_file_path}.")

# Get the service account JSON file path from the environment.
service_account_file_path = "/service-account-key.json"
print(f"Path to service account key set to {service_account_file_path}.")

# Create the service account credentials object.
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    service_account_file_path, ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher"]
)

# Create the API client object.
service = build("androidpublisher", "v3", credentials=credentials)

# Get an edit ID.
print(f"Creating an edit for bundle upload...")
request = service.edits().insert(packageName=app_id)
response = request.execute()
editId = response['id']
print(f"Edit ID for bundle upload is {editId}.")

with open(aab_file_path, "rb") as f:
  request = service.edits().bundles().upload(
      packageName=app_id,
      editId=editId,
      media_body=aab_file_path,
      media_mime_type="application/octet-stream",
  )
  print(f"Creating edit for bundle upload...")
  response = request.execute()
  versionCode = response.get("versionCode")
  print(f"Bundle version code is {versionCode}.")
  print(f"Commiting bundle upload edit...")
  request = service.edits().commit(editId=editId, packageName=app_id)
  response = request.execute()
  print(f"Bundle upload successfull.")

request = service.edits().insert(packageName=app_id)
response = request.execute()
editId = response['id']
release = {
  "versionCodes": [
    versionCode
  ],
  "releaseNotes": [
    {
      "language": "en_GB",
      "text": "Minor Improvements"
    }
  ],
  "status": "draft",
}
track = {
  "track": "internal",
  "releases": [
    release
  ]
}
request = service.edits().tracks().update(packageName=app_id, editId=editId, track="internal", body=track)
response = request.execute()
request = service.edits().commit(packageName=app_id, editId=editId)
response = request.execute()
```

It fails when uploading the bundle, with the following error message:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.company.app.app/edits/18014957208426515290:commit?alt=json returned "Only releases with status draft may be created on draft app.". Details: "Only releases with status draft may be created on draft app.">

The error message makes no sense, as I am not, in fact, trying to create a release at this stage. I'm simply trying to upload a bundle. So I just don't know how to proceed...

Note that I was able to upload a bundle manually AND create an internal testing release based on it. I was able to install it on my devices and it works as expected, so what I'm trying to do should be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not provide any information on why my first attempt was not working, but I randomly tried some things, one of them being doing both the bundle upload and the release creation in one edit, and that worked ¯_(ツ)_/¯. Here is the adjusted code for anyone encountering the same issue:

```
import os
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# Get the app ID from the environment.
app_id = "com.mycompany.myapp.app"
print(f"App ID set to {app_id}.")

# Get the APK file path from the environment.
aab_file_path = "/output/com.mycompany.myapp.app-Signed.aab"
print(f"Path to bundle set to {aab_file_path}.")

# Get the service account JSON file path from the environment.
service_account_file_path = "/service-account-key.json"
print(f"Path to service account key set to {service_account_file_path}.")

# Create the service account credentials object.
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    service_account_file_path, ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher"]
)

# Create the API client object.
service = build("androidpublisher", "v3", credentials=credentials)

# Get an edit ID.
print(f"Creating an edit for bundle upload...")
request = service.edits().insert(packageName=app_id)
response = request.execute()
editId = response['id']
print(f"Edit ID for bundle upload is {editId}.")

with open(aab_file_path, "rb") as f:
  request = service.edits().bundles().upload(
      packageName=app_id,
      editId=editId,
      media_body=aab_file_path,
      media_mime_type="application/octet-stream",
  )
  print(f"Creating edit for bundle upload...")
  response = request.execute()
  versionCode = response.get("versionCode")
  print(f"Bundle version code is {versionCode}.")

release = {
  "versionCodes": [
    versionCode
  ],
  "releaseNotes": [
    {
      "language": "en_GB",
      "text": "Minor Improvements"
    }
  ],
  "status": "draft",
}
track = {
  "track": "internal",
  "releases": [
    release
  ]
}
request = service.edits().tracks().update(packageName=app_id, editId=editId, track="internal", body=track)
response = request.execute()
request = service.edits().commit(packageName=app_id, editId=editId)
response = request.execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

First Release on Draft app MUST be manual

then after that, you must add `submit_as_draft: true` to your yaml

Comment: I have already done a manual release to the internal testing track. What yaml are you referring to ?

Comment: Hey @user16930239, I would gladly give you the bounty if you just clarify what yaml you are talking about and it solves my issue :) It expires in a few hours though.